# What is the most secure way to keep track of the current user in phone application

Tags: security, flutter, dart

I am currently creating a dart/flutter application and was wondering about the best way to save the current users' information. Currently, we have a user object that stores the information (name, email, profile picture, database id etc., no password or anything) that all pages reference when building things locally. When the user logs on, it retrieves their information from the database and recreates the object. My buddy who is also working on this application says that this way is not secure enough. If this is true, what is the most secure way to save user information locally, so that when a user goes to their profile page, my app doesn't have to reach out to the database every time to get their first name? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use package https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_secure_storage 
A Flutter plugin to store data in secure storage 
example code https://github.com/mogol/flutter_secure_storage/blob/develop/example/lib/main.dart

code snippet

```
import 'package:flutter_secure_storage/flutter_secure_storage.dart';

// Create storage
final storage = new FlutterSecureStorage();

// Read value 
String value = await storage.read(key: key);

// Read all values
Map<String, String> allValues = await storage.readAll();

// Delete value 
await storage.delete(key: key);

// Delete all 
await storage.deleteAll();

// Write value 
await storage.write(key: key, value: value);
```